# If Then statement/Smart value map

Tags: qgis

In QGIS I am working on a system to collect sewer data. At the moment I have like 25 manholes investigated. The information that I need are Material, shape and diameter of the sewer pipes.

At the moment I have three value maps:

Material:

- Concrete
- PVC
- Spirosol
- Stoneware
- Asbestos Cement

Shape:

- Round (Concrete)
- Egg shaped (Concrete)
- Square (Concrete)
- Round (PVC)
- Etc….

Diameter:

- 250mm (Round concrete)
- 300mm (Round concrete)
- 750/750mm (Square Concrete)
- Etc.

What I would like is that when I select concrete, only the shape options for concrete (Round/Egg shaped/Square) become available. When I then select for instance square, only the diameter for concrete square becomes available.

What I am looking for is some sort of If than statement in order to make it easier to register data.

Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Are you referring the data entry in the new feature forms?

Comment: Ehmm what do you mean exactly? I would like to have this for when I add new objects to my GIS but also for existing objects.

Comment: I belive what you want is in ESRI terms called domains and subtypes (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/exercise-3-creating-subtypes-and-attribute-domains.htm), might help you finding QGIS equivalents.

Comment: this blog post seems to describe exactly what you want: https://geosymp.com/build-dynamic-filters-values-drill-forms-qgis-form-aware-value-relation-widget/

Comment: It looks like for QGIS 2.x, you should use the plugin “Form Aware Value Relation Widget.” The plugin isn't available for QGIS 3.0. There's a crowdfunding campaign to develop this as a core feature for QGIS 3.2: https://north-road.com/drill-down-cascading-forms/